# What is the name of this type of form and what alternative are available?

Tags: website-design, forms, web-app, mobile-web

I'm designing a form for a web app and I'm looking for the name of this type of form element: [image]

Also, I'm trying to find alternative for small screens (mobile). I can't find any way to do this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Matching Information

Is an evaluation test type.

> The matching test item format provides a way for learners to connect a word, sentence or phrase in one column to a corresponding word, sentence or phrase in a second column. The items in the first column are called premises and the answers in the second column are the responses. The convention is for learners to match the premise on the left with a given response on the right. By convention, the items in Column A are numbered and the items in Column B are labeled with capital letters.

<sub>*From [theelearningcoach.com](http://theelearningcoach.com/elearning_design/writing-matching-test-items/)*</sub>

---

About small screens solutions there's already a [helpful answer here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/31183/115107).

To save space I would not hesitate to use a double screen with horizontal scrolling animation after selecting the first item and after clicking the second one to check the solution:

[image]